# How to change date formate , while importing excel in database php myadmin in codeigniter..?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to change date format while importing excel records in a database like if my excel date format is "03/06/2019" then, I want to change it to "2019-06-03".

```
date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($transactiondate))
```

I got my date in `$transactiondate` variable.

This is My Excel formate date.
[image]

This is My Out put after date post in codeigniter controller.
[image]

Comment: what is your output?

Comment: as  you can see your output contains non-datetime results. hence why you can't convert them to any other time.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($transactiondate));
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($date)
```

Comment: What is the output of `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($transactiondate));`?

Comment: like 1970-01-01

Comment: And what is the output of `$transactiondate`?

Comment: @Robert that only happens when your date isn't parseable so it defaults to unix epoch. if your date is truly what you say it is this code would work 100% (http://codepad.org/SJ1PTsRK).

Comment: maybe a `trim()` would be helpful if you extra whitespace